# Deploying Codebuild project into 4 ECS containers: The AWS ECS container **** does not exist

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I had pipeline running for single ecs service and now I have to deploy into 4 ecs service. I was able to create and push the images into repos sucessfully, but the issue comes in deployment.

I have renamed the task definition same as the `imagedefinition.json` file.

However, am still getting an error:

> Invalid action configuration The AWS ECS container ***** does not exist

Is it possible to deploy 4 containers at once??

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo "Install Scala ***********"
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Region(${AWS_REGION}) - ENV(${ENV}) - REPO(${REPO})"
      - VERSION=`date +%Y.%m.%d`-`echo ${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION} | cut -c1-10`
      - echo "Build Version ${VERSION}"
      - echo "Logging in to Amazon ECR (${AWS_REGION})"
      - eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ${AWS_REGION})
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Building"
      - sbt -no-colors docker:publishLocal
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo 
      - docker tag 
      - docker push  repo 1
      - echo 
      - docker tag 
      - docker push  repo 2
      - echo 
      - docker tag 
      - docker push  repo 3
      - echo 
      - docker tag 
      - docker push  repo 4
      - printf '[
        {"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"},{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"},{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"},
        {"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"},{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"},{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}
        ]'
        repo 1,
        repo 2,
        repo 3,
        repo 4,

        > imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

the code had to be removed for security reasons

Comment: Why did you remove the whole code without leaving at least an explanation? Was there any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is when I deploy into ecs it looks for all the container names in the ecs service that are  in image definition.json file  ,each service runs only one container , we can't use the same imagedefinition.json file for all the repos, we have separated it and zip it and use a lambda function to invoke it